# jQuery Mobile .popup() injection on AJAX navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm inserting the jQM popup widget via .js like so...

```
// jQM popup settings injection
// the variable "g_html_popup_settings" contains the markup for the settings popup(s)
// this var is established in application.html.erb
// popup injection 
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    var popupDOM = $("[data-role=popup]").length;
    if (popupDOM === 0) {
        // using enhanceWithin() as it triggers an update in presentation 
        // for injected widgets
        $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(g_html_popup_settings).enhanceWithin();
        // we use .popup() as of jQM 1.4.3
        //$("#iHODPopupSettings").popup("open");
        $('a[data-rel="popup"]').on("click", function () {
          $("#iHODPopupSettings").popup("open", {
            transition:"pop"
          });
        //console.log("creating popup...");
        }); //else {
        //console.log("There is a popup in the DOM!!");
    }
});
// /jQM popup settings injection
```

The var "g_html_popup_settings" is ruby/rails processed HTML.
I've been able to implement panel and toolbar jQM widgets this way to all areas of my app.
This widget is different as the popup has to be bound to a click event to produce the "modal"/popup.
When navigating to pages with jQM's default AJAX usage, I lose functionality of the button that opens the popup. The above way of injecting the widget works on all navigation using

```
data-ajax="false"
```

but, I'd like to have a solution where I didn't have to worry about if the page displayed came in via AJAX or not. I don't know if the 'pagebeforecreate' event is keeping me from doing some sort of universal presentation of the widget whether or not the pagecontainer load is AJAX or not.

All buttons are created using the following markup...

```
  <!-- settings modal button -->
  <a href="#IHODPopupSettings" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" 
  class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear">Settings
  </a>
  <!-- /settings modal button -->
```

Any help or insight with this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for reviewing this.

Comment: I guess - not sure though - you're appending the same popup multiple times and outside page, try this `$(".selector", e.target).length` and replace `$.mobile.pageContainer` with `$(e.target)`. Or any other option, on click, inject the popup dynamically and remove it once closed.

Comment: Hey Omar! Thanks for the suggestions. I tried to implement them, but couldn't exactly tell what order I should  have been using. I was getting an undefined error for the e. or event. After further inspection in Firebug/inspector, I noticed that the code/block of markup for the popup was still present in the DOM. I then added an else statement in the function above to recreate the click handler to make it available even if I wasn't initializing the popup widget. This seems to work. I think my rep is keeping me from posting the code in the correct format, but I'll work on that too. ;)

Comment: You missed the `e` in `function(e)`. `$(document).on("whatever", function (e) { console.log(e.target); });`

Comment: To clarify the above, the popup code/markup was present in the inspector for both AJAX and non-AJAX jQM navigation. I didn't see where anything was duplicated or recurring. When coming up with this solution, I did see mention on SO of memory leaks, etc. Hopefully, this way of injecting the popup won't contribute to that.

Comment: I dont know how ruby works in terms of navigation, whether Ajax is enabled. If you're able to register/attach click events, then the issue is easy. However, make sure events/listeners aren't duplicated. To find out, simply added attach a click event to one element/ID that is present in all views/pages, any function you want to process should work one time only not more. Here's a way of injecting a popup dynamically http://stackoverflow.com/a/25124660/1771795

Comment: That does work Omar. I'm not sure why, but I'm getting a UFOC (Unstyled flash of content) of only the footer being shown when using the e.target way of doing things. One second later, the footer arrives at the bottom and the jQM page renders fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58968/discussion-between-omar-and-dick-kirkland).