# jquery mobile 1.4: dynamic popup with image not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using dynamic popups for displaying images (google static maps) and it work's perfectly on JQM 1.3.2, but when i upgrade to JQM 1.4 it's not working anymore.

I also tried the demo example at
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/popup-dynamic/#demo-page
and it's not working.

anyone has an idea why or how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Try 1.4.4 instead of 1.4.1: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/popup-dynamic/#demo-page

Comment: Thanx it was fixed in 1.4.4, but i did many changes on the JQM 1.4.1 CSS and JS that i dont want to do that all over in 1.4.4/ you know what they fixed in 1.4.4 to enable that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25124660/1771795 JQM 1.4.x